# What is the best tool to make animations for iOS games?

Tags: animation, ios, games, retina

What is the easiest tool and way to make moving animations that can be used in iOS games? If there are tutorials, I can also learn. I also want it to be vector or retina. Something like hd. Thanks.

Comment: We need a lot more information here. What kind of animations are you talking about? Individual sprites? Objects moving on the screen? What IDE are you using to create the apps? You need to give us more specifics.

Comment: Like a person walking or swinging a sword.

Comment: 3d game or 2d? Vector style or 8-bit style? HTML/JS framework or Xcode? Are you using a particular gaming engine?

Comment: (In other words, what is 'best' depends entirely on all the other parts of the equation)

Comment: For a 2d side scrolling game. Vector style. Using Stencyl for easy programming.

Answer (score 4):

> For a 2d side scrolling game. Vector style. Using Stencyl

That is the key bit of info we needed!

Looking at their [documentation for animations](http://www.stencyl.com/help/view/animations/#importing) it looks like animation is handled within the app--meaning that you create the individual animations yourself outside, then import them as individual frames.

As such, it appears that the tool you need is a drawing tool to create said frames. What is 'easiest' is perhaps subjective, but some options that would fit your 'vector style' requirement would be Adobe Illustrator (commercial) or Inkscape (open source).

Both are vector illustration tools that will give you the style you are looking for that you can then use to create the individual frames for importing into Stencyl.

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I needed but there are no tutorials on creating animations on illustrator.

Comment: @hansy2010 if I understand the Stencyl documentation, you'd use Stencyl to create the actual animation. You'd use Illustrator to draw the individual frames. So if it's a person with a sword, you'd draw two pictures one with the sword on the left, one on the right, export them both as separate images, then import them both into Stencyl and create the animation there.

Answer (score 1):

Either of these tools could be all inclusive for this question and the one you asked about [general graphics](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29719/best-tools-to-make-game-graphics-for-ios-games)

For game development [Flash is still common](http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2012/12/ios-apps-flash-cs6.html) these days. If you want to go the html5/CSS3/SVG route, you can try [Adobe Edge Animate](http://html.adobe.com/edge/animate/), to assist, but it is not as mainstream as Flash.

Either way, with Illustrator and Photoshop also included, you should get yourself a subscription to Adobe Creative Cloud. You could also use After Effects (in CC too) if you are outputting the animations to video files.

Comment: Flash is not common at all for iOS development.

Comment: @DA01 Perhaps, but it is for game development in general and is compatible with iOS. Here is [the turbulent history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_and_Adobe_Flash_controversy#iOS_development)