# How do I specify the size of my artboard in pixels with Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, artboard, measurement

I'm creating a graphic for a website. When trying it out, I realized it was a bit blurry.

I asked a graphic designer the reason it was blurry, and she had stated the graphic may need to be larger, and to try the width at 1000 pixels.

How can I set a custom size for my artboard, to a specific number of pixels in Adobe Illustrator?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: A bit off topic (hence the comment) but I thought you might also find these tips interesting, related to "how to create crisp web images in AI": http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29719/what-software-should-i-use-to-make-crisp-game-graphics-for-ios-games/29730#29730

Answer (score 12):

Simply enter the number of pixels in the measurement fields, with the **Artboard Tool** selected...

[image]

*(You need first select the Artboard Tool to see the measurement fields in the Control Bar.)*

You can insert any number and any measurement system and Illustrator will honor it. 1000px, 1000pt, 1000p0, 100", 1000cm, 1000mm, etc.

You can also do the same thing in the new document window... enter whatever value you want...

[image]

You can also simply draw a rectangle the size you want in an existing document, then choose `Object > Artboards > Convert to Artboards` from the menu.

Comment: This answer might need to be edited, it looks like CC2018 doesn't have tools at the top anymore. Clicking twice on the Artboard icon in the tools drawer also lets the user specify desired dimensions.

Comment: @MicroMachine actually the *first sentence* in this answer states to select the Artboard tool first. But I did highlight that aspect a bit more.

Comment: In this screenshot, Artboard tool is selected and no text fields are to be seen on top of the screen (different from the first image in the answer): https://imgur.com/a/TqCrTGf

Comment: @MicroMachine turn on the **Control Bar**... Window > Control.. that should really *always* be on, at least that's how I set things.

Comment: That's a big detail! If you hadn't told me, I would have assumed they. had gotten rid of it...

Comment: It's on by default, similar to how the toolbar is on by default. You *had to have* disabled it at some point.

Comment: Sometimes preferences in illustrator get corrupted, toggled on/off by mistake (shortcuts), or just change without the user doing anything ("Hide edges" is another setting that toggles on and off, at one point I even thought it was document-specific)

Answer (score 2):

In the menu:
Illustrator > Preferences > Units
Set General to Pixels in the dropdown.
Then, you can set all the values to pixels because that is the default.

Comment: You can also do File > Document Setup > Units